# Continues Video Recording using OpenCv with Multiple Web cams. and streaming Video to Website

Tags: c++, opencv, streaming, timestamp

I'm a BSc student and im working on my final year project 
i have planned to create a security system using OpenCV with C++ using OOP using Ms visual Studio 2012, so far i have managed to capture video from multiple webcams and even record the video separately

However I realize that video only gets saved ones the application is closed. which leads me to another problem, because i would like to stream the recorded video live to a website.

Questions so far
1. Need to continuously record video and save to file
1. Need to Add time and date info (Time Stamp each frame)

Any form of help is much appreciated (code , links, or advice ) 
thanks in advance

Comment: 'video only gets saved once the application is closed' - that doesn't sound right, for a start.  You are buffering the entire video image stream? Gonna need a lot of RAM..

Comment: any solutions i didn't consider memory before let me run the code for an hour and c what happens